# "disconnecting" /dev/input/event14 from the tty

Tags: linux, events, usb, tty

I bought a USB foot switch. It has usb id 0c45:7403. Linux works perfectly fine with it, that is: if you press it, it emulates a keyboard-press.
Now I can simly open /dev/input/event14 and read events from it, but it seems there are still "key presses" being send to the tty! How can I prevent that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you spend only 4 minutes longer Googleing, you would've found the answer yourself!
First, open /dev/input/eventX - where X is 14 in your case. Then run:

```
int grab = 1;
int rc = ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, &grab);
if (rc == -1)
        // failure
```

From then, until your program stops, you own the device and no events end up at the tty.